# Angular 2+ Unit testing : disable console logs

Tags: angular, mocha.js, karma-runner

When I run `ng test` and some of my tests do not work, I have an issue : the logs are displayed in my console. Here is an example :

```
× should be created
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ConfirmationDialogService should be created FAILED
        Error: StaticInjectorError[MatDialog]:
          StaticInjectorError[MatDialog]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
            at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:993:1)
            at resolveToken C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1281:1)
            at tryResolveToken C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1223:1)
            at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1094:1)
            at resolveToken C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1281:1)
            at tryResolveToken C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1223:1)
            at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1094:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10878:1)
            at _createClass C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10915:1)
            at _createProviderInstance$1 C:/Users/MT4E45CN/Documents/Projects/POC/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10889:1)
```

I would like to delete this trace from my console, since I don't need it : I have set up my reporter to give me only the first lines of an error.

Is there a way to disable those logs ? (I assume they come from chrome console but I might be wrong by the way).

PS : I have tried to disable them with

```
client: {
  captureConsole: false
},
```

In my karma configuration, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `× should be created` is not `x` a variable in your test file?

Comment: Don't worry, I can handle the errors, I created this one on purpose. Anyway, to answer you, this isn't a x, this is a times symbol used by mocha (&times; in html code)